# Grep launches at "S+" state

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I'm trying to use grep in a machine but it just isn't working. When I use it after a pipeline (for example `ps -aux | grep grep`) it works (in the example showing grep processes).

But I'm trying for search a word into files but it just starts at S+ () state, no matter if I write "`grep anything`", "`grep -Ril anything`", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page:

> grep  searches  the  named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named ...

So when you run `grep anything`, `grep` is waiting for standard input.  You need to give it either filenames on the command line, or input via `stdin`.

Comment: Hmmm, this worked "partially", previously I remember other machine where i had to use other command (can't remember which) this way. So for looking for in a folder I need to specify the folder, but in other machines I am usually abled to just launch "grep anything" and anything is searched in the current path. Why is the difference?

The machine refusing to search in current folder is CentOS 5.6. The other machine where it is currently working is running CentoS 7.2.1511. Maybe it's just grep version? Maybe SO preferences?

Comment: It definitely could be a difference in grep version.  I see from the manual of grep version 2.27: If no input is specified, grep searches the working directory . if given a command-line option specifying recursion; otherwise, grep searches standard input.  So you wouldn't be able to "grep anything" on the newer version, according to this, but you would be able to "grep -r anything".  Does that match your experience?